# How to use ggplot with Processing in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, r, sextante, ggplot2, qgis-processing

I'm trying to use R scripts within QGIS thanks to Processing. There are some example scripts available and I achieved to plots different columns of the attribute table (with the plot built-in package).

What I cannot do is using the ggplot package. This is one of the simple code I've written:

```
##Vector processing=group
##showplots
##Layer=vector
##Field1=Field Layer
##Field2=Field Layer
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(Layer)+
geom_point(aes([[Field1]], [[Field2]]))
```

But none plot is shown.

Log output says:

```
R execution commands
options("repos"="http://cran.at.r-project.org/")
tryCatch(find.package("ggplot2"), error=function(e) install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE))
tryCatch(find.package("rgdal"), error=function(e) install.packages("rgdal", dependencies=TRUE))
tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error=function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
Layer = readOGR("/media/data/Universita/brema/gis/file_tesi/piezo_e_logger",layer="piezo_tutto_finale")
Field1="Br"
Field2="Ca"
png("/tmp/processing/f02d43598eb44b63aec89c02de38af54/RPLOTS.html.png")
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(Layer) + geom_point(aes(Layer[[Field1]], Layer[[Field2]]))

dev.off()
```

And that's a piece of the dbf table (trying to plot Cl vs Br):

```
ID                     Cl   Br
2818/22/0834    125.70  0.20
2818/22/0851    219.12  0.29
2818/22/0853    298.55  0.26
2818/22/0886    132.32  0.09
B0F                520.60   1.01
B12T           3435.49  3.83
B1T                2322.61  2.54
B21T           2800.90  3.18
B22F            366.87  0.64
B26T           1891.63  2.10
B33F            216.97  0.62
B4F                 383.98  0.44
P1                   82.01  0.14
P21                 365.56  0.74
P24                 199.98  0.73
P25                 308.71  0.90
P27                 217.58  0.58
P28                 436.09  0.32
P29                 711.77  1.08
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. No Layer call inside ggplot, here the right code:

```
##Vector processing=group
##showplots
##Layer=vector
##a=Field Layer
##b=Field Layer
library("ggplot2")

ggplot() + 
geom_point(aes(Layer[[a]], Layer[[b]]))
```

Cheers

Comment: Good that you got it working. The script worked for me however even with the Layer call inside. I am using ggplot2 version `O.9.3.1`

Comment: Maybe it's a qgis issue (I'm working with the master version, 2.1). Anyway, issue solved.. :)

Answer (score 3):

So why doesn't it work?

Look at your code, specifically the line with the attribute fields. You need to point R/QGIS directly towards the field data vectors unless you attach them beforehand.

The following code works without issues for me (provided that you have installed ggplot2):

```
##Vector processing=group
##showplots
##Layer=vector
##Field1=Field Layer
##Field2=Field Layer
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Layer) + geom_point(aes(Layer[[Field1]], Layer[[Field2]]))
# or save them beforehand into a vector: a <- Layer[[Field1]]
```

One example of a basic tutorial can be found on my [blog](http://conservationecology.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/port-your-r-scripts-to-qgis-using-sextante/).

EDIT:
If you don't have the library installed, than the r-code will of course produce no output. Try to replace `library(ggplot2)` with

```
if (!require(ggplot2)){print("ggplot2 not installed. Will install");install.packages(ggplot2, dependencies = TRUE)}
```

Comment: Hi Curlew, I've copied/pasted your code in the R script or Processing but the output is still a little question mark and none plot appears.  Maybe I'm missing some libraries?

Comment: Maybe you do :) Look at the log output and replace the `library(ggplot2)` with the following code (edited into answer)

Comment: That's really strange... I use R since month (with ggplot2, rgdal, raster packages installed), but look at the output log (edited in the post)

Comment: Another possible explanation could be that your field types are not numerical, but factorial (can even be caused by a NaN somewhere). Type conversion is important and Sextante won't show a seperate error here...

Comment: mmm.. I don't think that's the problem.. No NaN around here.. BTW: the sample ``Histogram`` script works (output is created), but if I try to plot two field with the simple ``plot`` function, it doesn't work..

Comment: Try to do the same just with the basic plot function. If this fails too than it has to do something with your data. As an alternative upload a small subset of your shape somewhere and i can try it out on my system. Besides that i can't help you anymore

Comment: With the basic ``plot`` function works, you that's a ggplot issue and there are no trouble with my data. I've edited my question with a small df. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Update: with `library("ggplot2") qplot((Layer[[a]], Layer[[b]])` works.. I have no idea why with the basic ggplot function I have these problems...